# RDS - Specify IP Addresses that can access RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

After following the AWS Documentation, I was able to successfully create an RDS DB Instance (PosgreSQL) and wondering if I could create a rule that limits the allowed IP addresses that can access the database.

I honestly don't know where to start again from here. I'm lost somewhere in AWS' documentation for like 2 hours. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone can point me to something useful.

My `Supported Platform` in RDS is `VPC` and I have a default `VPC` if that helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51285394/aws-rds-mysql-how-to-allow-access-after-setting-publicly-available/51298869#51298869

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to create a Security Group and create the rules there for the Inbound and outbound IP traffic that can communicate with RDS. You can specify there IP ranges, ports etc.

See: [Amazon RDS Security Groups - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html)

Comment: Hey lhay! I was able to make it work. Thanks for the reference!