# AWS RDS MySql - how to allow access after setting 'Publicly available'

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Just created new AWS RDS MySql instance with default settings and user/pass.

Also I set it to be `publicly available` and to create a new VPC during the process.

Currently can not connect from my laptop to this RDS:
`mysql -h endpoint -u myusername -p`

error:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'endpoint' (60)
```

How to allow access to it from e.g. my laptop and other computers? If is trough some security groups - where exactly to change and associate with new RDS instance trough console?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you telnet to the endpoint? ie `telnet somedomain.rdsendpoint.com 3306` On your laptop - if you nslookup (ie `nslookup somedomain.rdsendpoint.com` - do you get a public IP address returned?

Comment: Security groups - as you say this instance is within a VPC, you will need to use VPC security groups to grant access. See section here about VPC Security Groups: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html
This page will give guidance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the instance page, just under the monitoring graphs there is a `connect` block with a list of security groups.

There should be 1 group of type `security group - inbound`

On that security group's page you should have an `inbound` tab at the bottom.

[image]

Click on `Edit` et add a new rule for your current IP. Make sure the port is correct.

[image]

Now you should be able to connect with `mysql -h [ENDPOINT] -P [PORT] -u [USERNAME]  -p`

If you are behind a proxy this may still fail. You'll have to tunnel your way in or used a shared wifi connection.